# Scala abstract type bounds cross referencing

Tags: scala, type-bounds

I have two abstract classes which will hold references to each other.How / can I type bound the type members so as the types of HexT in the SideT members of the derived Hex classes will always be the derived Hex class? so for a derived class HexA it is guaranteed that: HexA#SideT#HexT = HexA

And similarly that the types of SideT in the HexT members of all the  derived Side classes will be the derived Side Class: SideB#HexT#SideT = SideB

I'm using Scala for Eclipse 2.1.0.M1 with Eclipse 3.7.2 All Classes are in separate files. The following compiles OK but doesn't guarantee what I want:

```
abstract class Hex { type SideT <: Side {type HexT <= Hex } }
abstract class Side { type HexT <: Hex {type SideT <= side } }
class HexC() extends Hex() { type SideT = SideC }
class SideC extends Side { type HexT = HexC }
```

But the following won't compile in the derived implementations:

```
abstract class Hex{type SideT <: Side {type HexT = this.type}}
abstract class Side{type HexT <: Hex {type SideT = this.type}}
class HexC() extends Hex(){
  type SideT = SideC //This won't compile
}
class SideC extends Side {
  type HexT = HexC //this won't compile
}
```

Is this correct? Should this compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
abstract class Hex {
  type SideT <: Side
}

abstract class Side {
  type HexT <: Hex
}

class HexC extends Hex {
  type SideT = SideC
}

class SideC extends Side {
  type HexT = HexC
}

val evidence1 = implicitly[SideC#HexT =:= HexC]
val evidence2 = implicitly[SideC#HexT#SideT =:= SideC]
```

Or with an encapsulating trait for the domain:

```
trait abstractDomain {
  type SideT <: Side
  type HexT <: Hex

  abstract class Hex
  abstract class Side
}

object domain extends abstractDomain {
  type SideT = SideC
  type HexT = HexC

  class HexC extends Hex
  class SideC extends Side
}
```

Or with type parameters:

```
abstract class Hex[HexT <: Hex[HexT, SideT], SideT <: Side[HexT, SideT]]
abstract class Side[HexT <: Hex[HexT, SideT], SideT <: Side[HexT, SideT]]

class HexC extends Hex[HexC, SideC]
class SideC extends Side[HexC, SideC]
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the top two solutions. Still bootstrapping my Scala understanding. I've seen the =:= combo before but can't find a ref to it. Funnily I tried the third soln months back in C#. The C# compiler wouldn't accept it. If possible I'd like to use abstract types within Hex and Side, although I will use generics for the collections that contain them.